# ASP.NET LinkButton not firing inside of Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, asplinkbutton

Using [Bootstrap's Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), ASP.NET LinkButtons are not firing events while inside of the tab-content div.

> HTML
>
> ```
> <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
>     <li role="presentation" class="active" runat="server" id="liQuestions" href="#questions" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
>         <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnQuestions" />
>     </li>
>     <li role="presentation" class="active" runat="server" id="liComments" href="#comments" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
>         <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnComments" />
>     </li>
>     <li role="presentation" class="active" runat="server" id="liAttachments" href="#attachments" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
>         <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAttachments" />
>     </li>
>     <li role="presentation" class="active" runat="server" id="liTracking" href="#tracking" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
>         <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTracking" />
>     </li>
> </ul>
>
> <div class="tab-content">
>     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="questions">
>         <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbQuestions" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
>     </div>
>     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="comments">
>         <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbComments" OnClick="lbComments_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
>     </div>
>     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="attachments">
>     </div>
>     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tracking">
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> C#
>
> ```
>     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         lbQuestions.Click += lbComments_Click
>     }
>     ...
>     protected void lbComments_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         Console.Write("This breakpoint never gets hit");
>     }
> ```

Neither methods of adding the OnClick event are firing while the LinkButtons are inside of the `<div class="tab-content">` div. 
Oddly, asp Buttons work perfectly. However I'm unable to use the Glyphicons inside of the Buttons, or just Glyphicons as buttons themselves if I have to settle for that. -- I also need the ability to use CommandArgument/CommandName, so a simple HTML button will not suite my needs either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely the JS that initializes the tabs plugin. Look at that preventDefault there:

```
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

Consider putting a class on the buttons that you want to behave as tabs and modify your JS to the following:

```
$('#myTabs a.myTabbedButton').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

Comment: This didn't end up being the specific problem I was having, although this answer got me looking in the right direction. -- It ended up being that I had some runat="server" 's on the <li>'s. -- Also, I see a bunch of stuff I rewrote incorrectly when I was hastily getting this question up, I appreciate you not attacking my demonstration code's syntax and actually addressing something that could have been the real issue! (I put the tab stuff on the <li>'s on accident instead of the buttons and forget a semi-colon)

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is in code itself..

**Parser Error Message: The tag contains duplicate 'role' attributes.**

Could you please check the code.

```
<li role="presentation" class="active" runat="server" id="liQuestions" href="#questions" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnQuestions" />
</li>
```

2 role is added (role="presentation" and role="tab").

**Also don't forget to add ";" after lbQuestions.Click += lbComments_Click**

It works fine for me.Hope you got the issue.